# To place a div at the last page only using print media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

**I have a container `div` which contains four `div` in it:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top"> this is top div</div>
    <div id="middle1"> this is middle1 div</div>
    <div id="middle2"> this is middle2 div</div>
    <div id="footer"> this is top div</div>
</div>
```

When I print this html, I want to place the footer `div` only at bottom of last page I print.

**This is my media query:**

```
@media print {
    #container{
        position:relative;
    }
    .middle1{
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .middle2{
        display:inline;
    }
    #footer{
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0;  
    }            
}
```

But this places the footer `div` at bottom of each page. I want the footer `div` only at bottom of last page.

Comment: place the footer div after the containe & try.

Comment: So what happen right now when you print the html ??

Comment: The footer is being shown at the bottom of each print page @junaid

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution: change the `position: fixed;` of footer to `position: absolute;`. You should read [**this article**](http://www.yorku.ca/nmw/facs1939f13/week02/css_relVSabsVSfixed.html).

```
@media print {
    #container{
        position:relative;
    }
    .middle1{
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .middle2{
        display:inline;
    }
    #footer{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;  
    }            
}
```

Why `position: absolute;` ?

Because

**1)** `#container` is `relative` so the `#footer` will be `absolute`, **but** `relative` to the `#container` (as `#container` is `position: relative;`)

**2)** As `#footer` is `bottom:0;` so using `position:absolute;` we make sure that `#footer` always remains at the bottom of `#container`.